# How I can use a commonjs module in my quasar project

Tags: node.js, vite, quasar-framework

I an SSR Quasar project using Vite. Whenever I try to add the `@tiptap/extension-code-block-lowlight` extension to my project, build it and then `node dist/ssr/index.js` it throws the following error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/whatever/devotto/devotto.com/node_modules/lowlight/lib/common.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /home/whatever/devotto/devotto.com/node_modules/lowlight/lib/common.js from /home/whatever/devotto/devotto.com/dist/ssr/server/server-entry.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename common.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /home/whatever/devotto/devotto.com/node_modules/lowlight/package.json.
```

Upon investigation, I have concluded that the issue is the `lowlight` library being imported by `@tiptap/extension-code-block-lowlight`.

If I manually go to my `node_modules/@tiptap/extension-code-block-lowlight/package.json` AND `node_modules/lowlight/package.json` and remove the line `"type": "module"`, I can run the project with no problem (e.g. `yarn build && node dist/ssr/index.js`.

This solution works on my current machine but I shouldn't have to touch the `node_modules` folder.

I would assume that I have to transpile `lowlight` library which prompts me to try to alter Vite configuration but no luck there as well

```js
module.exports = function() {
  return {
    build: {
      extendViteConf (viteConf, { isClient, isServer }) {
        if (isServer) {
          viteConf.optimizeDeps = viteConf.optimizeDeps || {};
          viteConf.optimizeDeps.include = ['./node_modules/highlight.js'];
          viteConf.build.commonjsOptions = viteConf.build.commonjsOptions || {};
          viteConf.build.commonjsOptions.include = [/highlight.js/, /node_modules/];

          // viteConf.optimizeDeps.entries = [
          //   'node_modules/@tiptap/extension-code-block-lowlight/dist/tiptap-extension-code-block-lowlight.cjs',
          //   'node_modules/highlight.js'
          // ];
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a solution to this issue without having to manually change `node_module` folder? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can use dynamic import from CJS to load an ES module.

Comment: @morganney do you mind adding an answer? I don't have experience in this area and I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: I don't use the technologies in your stack like vite, qusar, etc. and I am not sure if dist/ssr/index is your code or a dependency, but I do know you can use `import()` to load an es module from cjs. Are you able to try that?

Comment: @morganney `dist/ssr/index` is generated after building the project. You mean to try something like: `import TipTapCodeBlock from '@tiptap/extension-code-block-lowlight/dist/tiptap-extension-code-block-lowlight.esm'`?

Comment: No, use **dynamic** import. Also, if your dependencies are mostly esm have you considered using esm for your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't exactly solve the question. I only applied an automated way to handle this whenever I run the command to build the server using [pre scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts).

On my `package.json`:

```json
{
 "scripts": {
   "start:test:webserver": "ENV_FILE=test quasar build --mode ssr --port 3000 && node dist/ssr/index.js",
   "prestart:test:webserver": "sed -i '/\"type\": \"module\",/d' node_modules/lowlight/package.json && sed -i '/\"type\": \"module\",/d' node_modules/@tiptap/extension-code-block-lowlight/package.json",
 }
}
```